# Android: How to move a popup window and make this window not block other windows

Tags: android, popup, window, block, drag

I am new in android. Here is my question.
Is there pop up window can be moved in android? How to implement a popup window or other dialog that can be drugged. And can this pop up window not block other windows? When it pops up, I can still use other functions in main window.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use PopupWindow Class for this purpose refer the following link:
http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/

Comment: I have checked this link,but that popup-window can not be drug. Can it be moved with finger?

Comment: we can change position of popupwindow with code by specifying the x,y positions

Comment: Thank you,I just found we can define the onTouch to change positons

Answer (score 0):

here is sample code from my work , I make some comment to declare how its work

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              // your custom view
            View popView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_view, null);
             // initialise your pop window  
             // take custom view , with specific width , height
           PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) popView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            Button dismiss = (Button) popView.findViewById(R.id.disbutton);
            imageview.setImageURI(imagePath);

    // button used to open pop window 
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ChooseFile, 50, -30);

          // here is the part related to move popwindow    
            popView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                    int orgX = 0, orgY = 0;
                    int offsetX, offsetY;


                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            orgX = (int) event.getRawX();
                            orgY = (int) event.getRawY();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            offsetX = (int) event.getRawX() - orgX;
                            offsetY = (int) event.getRawY() - orgY;
                           // update popwindow postion , -1 set for width & height to make it fixed not changed 
                            popupWindow.update(offsetX, offsetY, -1, -1);
                            break;

                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });

            dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  // if you want dismiss your pop window 
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }
```